# Double-checked Locking for Shared Pointers

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, double-checked-locking

**Disclaimer:** I come from a Java background, and, as such, I have no clue on how a lot of the internals of C++ (and associated libraries) work.

I have read enough to know that double-checked locking is evil, and a correct and safe implementation of a singleton pattern requires the appropriate tools.

I believe the following code may be unsafe, subject to compiler reordering and assignment of uninitialized objects, but I am not sure if I am missing something that I do not understand about the language.

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> APtr;

APtr g_a;
boost::mutex g_a_mutex;
const APtr& A::instance()
{
  if (!g_a)
  {
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(g_a_mutex);
    if (!g_a)
    {
      g_a = boost::make_shared<A>();
    }
  }

  return g_a;
}
```

I believe the actual code is compiled under C++03.

Is this implementation unsafe? If so, how?

Comment: IMHO, reading as writing without lock is bad : whats append if someone write inside `g_a` when you start to read it ? nothing ensures you that a reading isn't interrupt by a process which will write `g_a`, and continues just after. Remove first `if(!g_a)` and it will be safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is absolutelty unneccesary in modern C++. Singleton code should be as simple as this for anybody but dinosaurs:

```
A& A::instance() {
    static A a;
    return a;
}
```

100% thread safe in C++11 and up.

However, I have a mandatory statement to make: Singletons are evil antipattern and should be banned forever.

### On thread safety of original code

Yes, provided code is unsafe. Since the reading is done outside the mutex, it is totally possible that the modifications to `g_a` **itself**  would be visible, but not that modifications to the object `g_a` is pointing to. As a result, the thread will bypass mutex locking and return a pointer to non-constructed object.

Comment: I have seen that suggestion elsewhere, but I do not own the code in question, I am just analysing it, and I believe the actual binaries are compiled under C++03. I will get that cleared up. I wholeheartedly agree that singletons should be banned, however.

Comment: @afsantos, the code is unsafe. I have explained why.

Comment: Exception to the "Singletons are evil anti pattern" rule -- if the returned singleton object is immutable, then it's okay, since there can be no thread-safety problems if the object is never modified

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, first, antipatterness of singletons has nothing to do with thread-safety. It is an antipattern even in single-threaded applications. Second, when we talk about singleton thread-safety, we usually refer to it's creation, not the thread-safety of "underlying" object. Because of that, being immutable is irrelevant for singleton thread-safety concept.

Comment: @SergeyA the alternative is to have each caller construct and use its own separate (yet 100%-identical) object instead, which uses additional memory and CPU time, for no obvious benefit in the immutable-object case.  Regarding thread-safety of the object's creation, your post says your example is "100% thread safe in C++11 and up", so it seems that is not an issue.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, no, alternative is to use a const global object.

Comment: Sure, that works too.  Wrapping it in an accessor function gives a bit more flexibility/encapsulation, though.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the double-checked locking pattern is unsafe in archaic languages. I can't do any better than the explanation in [What's wrong with this fix for double checked locking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945232/whats-wrong-with-this-fix-for-double-checked-locking?rq=1):

> The problem apparently is the line assigning instance -- the compiler is free to allocate the object and then assign the pointer to it, OR to set the pointer to where it will be allocated, then allocate it.

If you were using C++11 `std::shared_ptr`, you could use [`atomic_load` and `atomic_store`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) on the shared pointer object, which are guaranteed to compose correctly with each other and with mutexes; but if you're using C++11 you may as well just use a dynamically-initialized `static` variable, which is guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Comment: It's not only the initialzation code. It might be CPU cache playing tricks here. It might be an optimization in compiler, which does really funny things with order of execution, assignments to main memory, etc.